# CSS is rendering a weird rectangle when i refresh my page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just finished my website, just testing stuff in css, when i noticed that when i refresh my page for like 1 second theres a weird rectangle on the  screen. 
I dont have any idea what that is...

> Thats how it looks like:

[image]

```css
body, html    {
    height: 100%;
}
*   {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.bg-img {
    background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ1dheaD1dxyVt36DttKPFYNm9GHuGVfMYDjSOicpB2gVIk_Vq1_w");
    height: 100%;
    filter: blur(4px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
.date-box {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.25);
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 3px solid whitesmoke;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>time tho</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/indexstyles.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jscript/datefw.js"></script>
</head>
<body scroll="no" style="overflow: hidden">
    <div class="bg-img"></div>
    <div class="date-box">
        <h1 id="phms"></h1>
        <p id="pdate"></p>
    </div>
    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://discordapp.com/users/222015592738062336"><p id="stax">by stax</p></a>
    <script>
        drawOverlay();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Thats when i reload the page(just for a split second):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself!
I just used the function `window.onload`
So i rendered the box after the page was fully loaded. Simple as that :D

```css
.date-box-hide {
    display: none;
}
.date-box-show {
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .4);
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 3px solid whitesmoke;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body scroll="no" style="overflow: hidden">
    <div class="bg-img"></div>
    <div id="hide" class="date-box-hide">
        <h1 id="phms"></h1>
        <p id="pdate"></p>
        <script>
            window.onload=function()
            {
                document.getElementById("hide").className="date-box-show";
            };
            drawOverlay();
        </script>
    </div>
    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://discordapp.com/users/222015592738062336"><p id="stax">by stax</p></a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that's just the `.date-box` element without any content. You may try adding a `min-width` and `min-height` value to your `.date-box` CSS rule to make the box the size you want before the date/time is fully loaded, like so:

```
.date-box {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.25);
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 3px solid whitesmoke;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 300px;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

It's a really cool looking start, you have there. Keep it up!

Comment: Thanks, i really appreciate it! :) But it didnt fix my problem sadly, it made the filled border just as big as the values i entered :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess the box is the div `.date-box`. Perhaps you put the content of `#pdate` and `#phms` by your JavasScript function `drawOverlay()`. Since then, until the function runs, those divs are empty.

To solve the problem, hide the `.date-box` default and show it after content has filled like below for example.

CSS

```
.date-box {
    display: none;
}
```

and JS

```
drawOverlay()
document.querySelector('.date-box').styles.display = "block"
```

Comment: I have no variable called .styles after the querySelector

Comment: It should be `style`, not `styles`. Simple typo.

Comment: No, dont have that one either, nothing that begins with sty